# Can an instance of amazon ec2 be upgraded automatically from sql server 2008 r2 to sql server 2012?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is there a tool from Amazon or Microsoft to automatically upgrade an ec2 instance's sql server 2008 to 2012?  Or do I have to create a new instance and then import all the databases?

Comment: Clarification: the database is on EC2, correct? Not RDS?

Comment: It is an EC2 instance of Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the joys of EC2 is that you can create instances so easily, for the tiny cost of a few hours of runtime. I've had so many system upgrades (win/mac/unix) go wrong that I would recommend doing a test run on a different instance no matter what.

But to answer your question, I know of no Amazon tools for updating an instance from 08 to 12. [Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx) contains enough **Notes** and **Cautions** that I would be careful with any tools from them as well.

That web page does say specifically:

> Upgrade of an earlier version of SQL Server to SQL Server 2012 is not
>   supported on a computer that is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core SP1.